# Миграция данных из из старой базы в новую

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных, django, миграция

Вопрос - есть старая версия проекта, от которой мы хотим отказаться, есть новая версия, где уже как полгода идет работа и есть какие то данные. Но есть проблема - миграция данных. К примеру, в старом проекте есть в таблице clients запись с id 1, и в новой базе есть запись в таблице clients с id 1. Как правильно перенести данные из старой базы в новую и избежать потерю данных с обоих сторон, при этом сохранив связи между таблицами (к примеру, записи в таблице clients имеют отношение к таблице deals "Одно-к-Многим").
База данных - MySQL.

Comment: Если я верно понимаю - средствами СУБД, минуя фреймворк? Ну, например, ко всем ID и ссылкам в старой БД добавить некое заведомо достаточное, чтобы избежать дублирования, смещение. Для строковых полей придумать ещё что-то - например, добавить в конце неразрывный пробел... С другой стороны, если полгода старые данные не требовались - так ли они нужны?

Comment: @Akina да нужны=( что добавить к id и ссылкам?

Comment: Ну прибавить по миллиарду, например, если в тип вкладываетесь... маловероятно, что ваши автоинкременты когда-нибудь добредут до этих значений.

Comment: пользуйтесь django-import-export, и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: Если делать все по-правильному, то смотрите в сторону написания скриптов миграции. Можно с помощью sql, можно с помощью стороннего ЯП

Comment: @suit Вы о чем вообще? Какие скрипты миграции? Давно всё написано.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, я про общий случай. Касательно django не в курсе просто, поэтому написал комментом, а не в ответы.